How to get admin controller url to js without using phtml file?
I have created new mass action for product grid, So whenever someone click on that mass action, custom admin controller url should be pass to js

define([
'jquery',
'mage/url'
], function ($,url) { 

var linkUrl = url.build('frontname/regions/index');
console.log(linkUrl);
});

You have to pass your admin url

@Mark
Hey, please follow the given code:
<?xml version="1.0" Programmatic Solutionencoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <action name="barcode">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">massoperation</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Mass Action</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="extension/controller/massaction"/>
                        <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom Mass Action</item>
                            <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure want to Perform Custom
                                Action For selected items?
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
        </massaction>
        <paging name="listing_paging"/>
    </listingToolbar>
</listing>

Thank You!
